# Is there a way to get a reference to a Select list based on its title

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a third party tool and i want to get the reference for 2 select list, now i am referencing these by the ID as follow:

```
var customer = document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl06_DropDownChoice");
var selectobject = document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl07_DropDownChoice");
```

but the select lists have Title for them , so can i base the selection based on the Title rather than Ids.. now i tried the following:

```
var customer =  $("select[title='Main Category Required Field']");
```

but the customer will be null.

here is the HTML for one one the select lists:

[image]

Comment: can you pls provide the html

Comment: From the format of the `id` attributes I assume you're using ASP.Net WebForms. If so, look in to using the `ClientID` of the element instead

Comment: Your code seems ok. You should check html that rendered with browser `F12` and make sure that title is identical to your script title.

Comment: Can you post an HTML snippet as well?

Comment: @SamuelJMathew ok i uploaded a screen shot of the markup,, can u check it please?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there is not a clientId,, please check the markup

Comment: @StavrosAngelis done..

Comment: @teovankot yes it is identical ... can you please check the updated question where i provided the markup

Comment: You've provided a picture of the DOM, not the ("*[mcve]*") HTML that's sent, as text, to your browser. And rather than blanking the text of the elements, maybe just change it to something that's not confidential? Also, you've asked - as I write this - 888 questions, and a rep of 3.75k; why do you need prompting as to "*[ask]*"?

Comment: @johnG `there is not a clientId,, please check the markup` Exactly my point, you need to add one

Comment: (1) You should be using the id as present in the markup. It should work and I assume it ***is*** working because you didn't mention that in your question. (2) Present an MCVE. (3) [The title works](https://jsfiddle.net/yb72yaLq/) (*the second select should be yellow*). (4) Why it isn't working for you would be impossible for anyone to guess without an MCVE.

Comment: @johnG it will work you can check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0vgo1jkb/

Answer (score 0):

The selector `var customer =  $("select[title='Main Category Required Field']");` you use is ok.

If you want to take the value of the select list and not the entire element your selector should be

```
var customer =  $("select[title='Main Category Required Field']").val();
```

I don't know how you append your select list in the DOM and how it's populated with values but do make sure that your selector is used after the DOM is loaded like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var customer =  $("select[title='Main Category Required Field']").val();
    alert(customer);
});
```